# Unit testing framework - POS application

Tags: c++, c, unit-testing, embedded-linux, point-of-sale

I am in a project where we application for POS devices. 
The language is C/C++, we use a cross-compiler, eclipse kepler and ubuntu.
I wonder what is the best unit testing framework for my case.
I would like to use something enough documented and preferably simple.

I tried with CppUTest but I dont find the documentation for its eclipse plugin to be sufficient  https://github.com/cpputest/CppUTestEclipsePlugin.

Another  personal experience on a unit test framework using this environment would very be helpful.

Comment: Answering the reopen request: This question will be kept close because it doesn't fit in the question and answer format accepted in the site yet. Feel free to change and ask for reopen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GTest is an easy to use framework that is relatively portable and doesn't carry around to many dependencies.

It won't allow you to do anything overly fancy, but I've always found it extremely easy to use, generic to work with any project, and takes minimal amounts of setting up. It also works in conjunction with GMock to add support for mocks which is always nice. It takes a little over ten minutes to set up and compile. From there it's extremely easy to setup a test bed and it is easily extendable.

Here's a link to the sample page.
https://code.google.com/p/googletest/source/browse/trunk/samples/sample1_unittest.cc

Answer (score 0):

I think [CppUnit](http://cppunit.sourceforge.net/doc/lastest/cppunit_cookbook.html) would be suitable for your case since you use Eclipse and C/C++. I think it is well documented and you can find lots of examples about that.

Comment: thanks, are you personally using that or you did previously?

Comment: yes, i started using it and i think that its efficent